# Setting height of img tag equal to its width

Tags: html

Well I googled it a lot but didn't find anything useful.is there any way to achieve this ?

```
<img src="1.jpg"height="" width="100%">
```

Comment: I think you need javascript for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth):

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

img.style.height = img.offsetWidth + "px";
```

And you will have to use JavaScript.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AX823/)**